# Проверка работоспособности системных вызовов *nix-систем

Tags: linux, c, macos, syscall, bsd

Доселе в системное программирование не окунался, по-сему, если вопрос покажется неточным/наивным/глупым - прошу помочь его сформулировать правильно.

Пока интересуют два "механизма": [`kqueue`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) и [`epoll`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) (и отчасти [`IOCP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_completion_port))

**Вопрос**

Как программно узнать что нужный механизм на исполняемой системе реализован и работоспособен?

**Детали**

Перечисленные "механизмы" (за исключением `IOCP`, наверное, не знаю) изначально не были реализованы. А добавлялись в функционал с каких-то версий ядер. Как написано в сети, к примеру, `kqueue` во `FreeBSD` - начиная с версии 4.1, `epoll` в `Linux` - начиная с 2.5.44 версии ядра. Пока вижу для себя единственный вариант - да, смотреть версии. Но, что-то подсказывает, что это не правильно, вернее, не совсем правильно.

Как более правильно?

Comment: думаю стоит посмотреть в сторону autoconf

Comment: @Mike , конечно глянуть нужно. Но это билд-тайм, а вопрос о ран-тайме.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь запустить приложение, собранное например для использования epoll на glibc в которой физически нет этой функции. Загрузчик сильно обидится и не позволит приложению запустится. Если же вы соберете приложение статикой - то оно запустится, но вызовет несуществующий syscall, надо посмотреть что ядро делает с процессами вызывающими не те вызовы ...

Comment: Совершенно пока не знаю - те же разработчики Qt позволяют себе  изготавливать бинарные инсталляторы. Но они указывают дистрибут и ядро. А если я запущу "не там"? И еще ... на что может "обидиться" загрузчик, если приложение слинковано в статике?

Comment: Ну, существует два формальных подхода: тест на стабильность (fuzzer) и тест на совместимость. Второй называется, например, TET, стоит что-то порядка $100k без права использования результатов в опенсорсе. Про первые для BSD даже не слышал. Для Linux есть бесплатные и открытые первые и даже какие-то вторые (ну и тот же TET). https://www.opengroup.org/testing/testsuites/

Comment: В момент выполнения результат вообще не предсказуем. потому как надо выполнить syscall, а какой именно syscall вызывается передается в ядро его номером. Номера фиксированы в заголовочных файлах ядра и libc их от туда берет на этапе своей компиляции. т.е. если система не та, для которой собрана и каким то чудом программа запустилась, то нельзя предсказать что выполнит ядро получив тот syscall который вы выполните, может быть выполнено произвольное действие, потому что ядро будет полагать что вы вызываете совершенно иную функцию

Comment: Вот поэтому и существует autoconf и поэтому все программы, распространяемые бинарниками, собираются отдельно для разных версий системы. И чаще всего не собираются статикой.

Comment: Да ... вариант - нужно как-то проверить

Comment: **нельзя предсказать что выполнит ядро получив тот syscall который вы выполните, может быть выполнено произвольное действие** Это не так. Все коды вызовов syscall перечислены в файле */usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h*. В документе 'man 2 syscalls' перечислены все эти коды и для каждого указано, НАЧИНАЯ С какой версии ядра этот код работает. Но, ни один код и никогда не отменялся. Поэтому, если Ваша программа сделает вызов 'syscall' в старом окружении, в котором этот код ещё не реализован, то она получит сообщение об ошибке. Но НИКОГДА не будет выполнено другое действие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я буду говорить про Linux, так как про FreeBSD ничего не знаю.
Начнём с того. что *epoll* (так же как и *poll*) - системный вызов. Т.е. это вызов ядра посредством ioctl.

Поддерживается эта возможность ядром (данным конкретным ядром), или нет, можно узнать просмотрев конфигурационный файл генерации этого ядра с помощью *make menuconfig*. Там можно прочитать:

```
 CONFIG_EPOLL:
  Disabling this option will cause the kernel to be built
  without support for epoll family of system calls.
```

В man читаем:

> epoll_create() was added to the kernel in version 2.6.  Library
>   support is  provided  in  glibc starting with version 2.3.2.

Ядро, версии младше 2.6 Вы сейчас вряд-ли найдёте. Т.е. поддержку epoll следует ожидать во всех ядрах, если данное конкретное ядро не было сгенерированно специально БЕЗ этой опции.

Я вижу только один путь проверить это в программе:

- Вызвать функцию epoll_create()
- Если она вернула -1 - произошла ошибка
- Если в переменной errno записано значение EPERM - операция недопустима.

Скорее всего, это будет означать что использовать epoll невозможно.
М.б. в качестве альтернативы - inotify ?

Comment: плюсанул, хороший ответ. Кстати ... а как поведет (должен повести) себя Линукс при вызове "неправильного/нереализованного" сискола? И как такое обработать по фэн-шую?

Comment: Вы говорите о вызове функции syscall() ? Это довольно редкое явление в Linux, т.к. : "Employing  syscall()  is useful,  for  example,  when  invoking  a  system call that has no wrapper function in the C library." Таких случаев немного, в основном, все библиотечные "обёртки" используют вызов ioctl().  В любом случае, признаком вызова нереализованной функции ядра будет значение errno == EPERM.